# How can I get all days (name, number) of 4 weeks from current day (in the future)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get all days 4 weeks from my current day. For example, today is June (Thu, 23), I want to get (24, Fri) .... up until (21, Thu) July.

Comment: for loop 1-28, and each time call DateTime.add(Duration(days:1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate days like

```dart
  late List<DateTime> days = List.generate(
    7 * 4, // 4weeks
    (index) => DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(days: index+1),
    ),
  );
```

And to get days name I am using [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. and formatter is

```
final formatter = DateFormat('EEEE');
```

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: days.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
            "name: ${formatter.format(days[index])} number:${days[index].day}  "),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. And another thing, what if I want to go 4 weeks in the past, what should I change? Thanks!

Comment: use `.subtract` instead of `.add` on date.

Answer (score 0):

Using DateFormat

```
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('MMMMd');
    _nextDateFormatted = formatter.format(widget.nextDate);
```

In your case, you will have 4 dates. Heres with the first date

```
_firstDateFormatted = formatter.format(DateTime.now().add(days:1).millisecondsSinceEpoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<dynamic> data = [];
                        for (int i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
                          data.add(DateFormatters()
                              .dMy
                              .format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i))));
                        }
                        log("$data");
```